# Not able to automatically parallelize for loop with numba

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba

I am trying to run the following on multiple cores for speed up using numba. Unfortunately the function seems to run only on one core when I tested it. Can someone explain to me why and if there is a possibility to get it running on multiple cores?

Minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

a = np.random.rand(100000)

@numba.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def func(x):
    result = np.zeros_like(x)
    for delta in range(1,len(x)):
        thisresult = 0
        for i in range(delta,len(x)):
            thisresult += (x[i] - x[i-delta])**2
        result[delta] = thisresult / (len(x) - delta)
    return result

print(func(a))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explicit Parallelization

I would always remommend to parallelize code explicitely. Numba tries to serialize some parallel code parts, but that won't always work or lead to best performance.

```
import numpy as np
import numba 

a = np.random.rand(100000)

@numba.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def func(x):
    result = np.zeros_like(x,dtype=x.dtype)
    for delta in numba.prange(1,len(x)):
        thisresult = 0
        for i in range(delta,len(x)):
            thisresult += (x[i] - x[i-delta])**2
        result[delta] = thisresult / (len(x) - delta)
    return result

print(func(a))
```

For more details have a look at the [documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/parallel.html).

Comment: I suppose I can change the second `range` for `numba.prange` as well?

Comment: This would actually a bit slower. But the outer for loop could be rewritten to gain some performance (the calculation time decreases with growing delta).